# Can I install SharePoint Online site definitions in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extentions\15\TEMPLATES?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-definition

I know SharePoint site designs normally get installed to that directory when SharePoint server is installed. However, is it possible to install the site defenitions in SharePoint online?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot install anything server-side. You should start looking at [Site Designs](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview) and possibly [Azure Automation](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/automation/automation-intro) called from Power Automate to replace classic SharePoint site templates.